# How to authenticate users every time they send print commands

Tags: c#, printing, windows-services, drivers, form-authentication

Need an idea to write a code to authenticate users before they send the commands to print.

Initial idea is to create a windows service which could bypass the call to the 
printer driver and can open a form for login credentials.

so that only the authenticated users who qualifies the monthly quota for printing the pages could access the printer.

Please share your views whether this approach is feasible and how this can be achieved.

Comment: Care to explain for the negative remark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the `Win32_PrintJob` WMI Class or the `winspool.drv`. You will find additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084052/prevent-user-from-printing) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51085/Monitor-jobs-in-a-printer-queue-NET?fid=1556859&select=4799234). Also, have a look at the [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162722(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Monitor the `Win32_PrintJob` WMI Class and pause the print job. Resume the job if the user has not reached the monthly quota. Otherwise, delete it.

Comment: Thanks a lot hofmeister for the valuable direction.. It makes sense.